# Where to enter app settings, tests and contracts/interfaces in a n-tier architecture?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, architecture, projects-and-solutions, n-tier-architecture

I'm creating an n-tier application with Visual Studio 2010.

I have a project with only app configs, a project with only tests, and a project with only contracts (interfaces).

In a logical model, where should you enter application config values, tests and contracts?

Is this good practice?

[image: Solution of my project]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want separate test projects for each project you are testing. Assuming they are truly unit tests, then e.g. `VENUS.Repository.Tests` will only reference `VENUS.Repository` directly. In practice this will probably not quite pan out unless you mock *everything*, but still, separating the projects will give you much more clarity of purpose.

---

I think a separate project for "contracts" (interfaces I assume) is misguided. Interfaces are the public entry point that one layer uses to reference other layers. As such, they belong in their respective layers. That is, `IFooRepository` belongs in `VENUS.Repository`, not in `VENUS.Contracts`. (But, see discussion in the comments.) If you put them all in one assembly, you are destroying the n-tier separation by saying "anyone who wants to interface with any layer, just reference `VENUS.Contracts` and you can run wild."

---

Finally, and this is a bit more situational, but my instinct would be to have a single config file in your composition root (usually the UI layer), and inject the configuration dependencies into the components as you compose them. So e.g. a connection string doesn't go in `VENUS.Config` which gets referenced by `VENUS.Repository` (as well as everyone else), but instead goes in `VENUS.UI.Web`'s `app.config`. Then, when `VENUS.UI.Web` composes its repository dependency, it passes that configuration in to the repository constructor. For example:

```
string fooConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Foo"].ConnectionString;
IFooRepository fooRepo = new SqlFooRepository(fooConnectionString);
// Now, as you compose the rest of your dependencies,
// inject fooRepo into anything that requires an IFooRepository.
```

(This is of course an example of "poor man's dependency injection"; if you plan on using a proper dependency injection framework there will be nicer ways of doing the composition.)

This way your repository layer has no conceptual dependency on the concept of "configuration," but instead just expresses what it needs in the natural way of object-oriented programming: constructor parameters.

Comment: I notice you said put IFooRepository in the Repository project.  That was my thinking until I started reading ASP.NET Design Patterns by Scott Millett.  He was putting the IFooRepository in the Domain layer.  I originally found his way odd but I guess you can make a case for both.  Example: You create a new project called SQLRepository you would reference the domain model which holds the IFooRepository contract.

Comment: @Beavis: good call, you are right. That idea, which I fully support, stems from the Onion Architecture paradigm: http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/